# Local server/Apache not working after installing and removing DNSMasq - macOS Sierra

Tags: linux, bash, apache, homebrew, dnsmasq

I installed DNSMasq with Brew to run virtual hosts but quickly decided I did not want to run vhosts and have uninstalled and (tried to) remove DNSMasq.

I'm unsure what this has done to the machine's nameserver but now my 127.0.0.1 'cannot be reached'. Apache is running but I cannot reach the server. I tried to debug through `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager` but could not find the directory and I'm unsure where the default network manager configuration file is and how to edit this.

I have a feeling `etc/resolver/dev` may be causing the issue.

DNSMasq was installed by -

`brew install dnsmasq`

`cd $(brew --prefix); mkdir etc; echo 'address=/.dev/127.0.0.1' > etc/dnsmasq.conf`

`sudo cp -v $(brew --prefix dnsmasq)/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons`

`sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist`

`sudo mkdir /etc/resolver`

`sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolver/dev'`

I cannot remember now what command I used to uninstall.

`/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist` still remains.

httpd.conf has been reset to original file and vhosts commented out.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Despite bash being the shell you used to echo some contents to a file, I still don't see any relevance for the bash tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but problem was with apache configuration after upgrading brew.

Try this to see the errors: `sudo apachectl -t`

Comment: Thanks @Denis . The error reads 
"AH00526: Syntax error on line 10 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf:
Invalid command 'UserDir', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"